# How to call WSDL2JAVA from ant with whitespaces in my path

Tags: java, windows, ant, whitespace

HI guys!

I try to call Axis2 WSDL2JAVA in my ant file to create a WSDL client. But it's broken because I have whitespaces in my path (I'm on Windows...). This is my ant

```
<property name="wsdl.file" location="C:\path with whitespaces\project\subdir\my.wsdl"/>
...
<target name="generate.client" depends="Clean.Client">
    <java  classname="org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java">
        <arg value="-uri" />
        <arg file="${wsdl.file}"/>
        <arg value="-u"/>
        <arg value="-p"/>
        <arg value="my.package.declaration"/>
        <arg value="-S"/>
        <arg value="src/test"/>
        ...
        <classpath refid="axis2.classpath"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

When I try to run it, I get this errors:

```
[java] Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 18: file:/C:/path with whitespaces/project/subdir/my.wsdl
 [java]     at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2809)
 [java]     at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:2982)
 [java]     at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3066)
 [java]     at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3014)
 [java]     at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:578)
 [java]     at org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.DefaultURIResolver.resolveEntity(DefaultURIResolver.java:57)
 [java]     ... 39 more
```

I tried to add *& quot;* to my property, but it doesn't work and gives me a doubled path then. I also tried to change the nested *arg value=* to *arg line=* but it's the same.

Is this really a but that stops me from building from a directory with whitespaces? I can't believe it's still happening these days... :-(

**Update** I can't move the project to get rid of the whitespaces.

Comment: Does index 18 refer to the *position* of the Illegal character in the path with whitespaces, or something else? I can't see that it's the former. BTW how do you escape funny characters? I see that the backspace has the usual meaning in MS pathname.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I changed the real path and forgot the index. It corresponds to the position of the illegal character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an URI the blanks must be escaped as %20

Comment: Can I do it with standard ant or do I have to use the ContribTask UrlEncode?

Comment: Oh, and btw. WSDL2JAVA wants an URI or a path, so I think I don't need to URLencode it:


     [java] Usage: WSDL2Java [options] -uri <url or path> : A url or path to a WSDL

Comment: Your code is passing the file as a path. If your are not using the property anywhere else, you can set it to a syntactically correct URI. If you want the property to be a file path however, you will need to use the ContribTask UrlEncode.

Comment: I was using the project ${basedir}. For now I hardcoded the project path with shortcuts as described by **akf** in a comment. I think I have to use UrlEncode to get rid of the hardcoded path. :-/ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on Windows, you have the option to use shortnames for your directories.  You use the `dir /x` command on your directories to find the shortnames.  For example, `dir /x c:\` will list the files and directories on your C:\, including the root of "path with whitespaces", without the whitespaces.

A common shortname that you will find helpful is that for "Program Files", which generally resolves to 'PROGRA~1'.

In your example, the path might turn out to:

```
C:\pat~1\project\subdir\my.wsdl
```

However, it would be best, as mentioned above, to test the path out by using the dir command (both with the `/x` to get the shortname, and then after again, to test the use of the shortname.

Comment: I'm not using hardcoded directory names, I'm using the project $basedir which is set as ".".

Comment: I used the short name as a hardcoded value now, but I really have to get rid of it. So I think I'll get the ContribTask UrlEncode in my ant. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Latest Axis2 Version (1.6.2) still has this problem:
Creating an URI with whitespaces replaced by %20 is best done using the makeurl function:

```
<makeurl file="${wsdl.src}" property="wsdl2java.uri"/>
<java classname="org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java" fork="true">
    <arg line="-uri ${wsdl2java.uri}"/>
     <arg line="-S ${src.dir}/"/>
       [...]
    <classpath>
       <path refid="axis2-classpath"/>
    </classpath>
</java>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution is to get rid of those pesky whitespaces.  Trust me, you'll be glad you did.

Comment: Moving the project isn't an option... :-/